# Disabling Button in Android inside a fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments

I have a button inside a fragment and I can't seem to get the right code to disable it. Please help me :)

Below is the code that I tried and it is not working..

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

the full code of where it is being used is below.

```
public class TabFragmentTwo extends Fragment  {
private static final String ARG_EXAMPLE = "this_is_a_constant";
private String example_data;
String var_selected_Split =null;
String varSplit=null;

public TabFragmentTwo() {

}

public static TabFragmentTwo newInstance(String example_argmument) {
    TabFragmentTwo tabFragmentTwo = new TabFragmentTwo();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_EXAMPLE, example_argmument);
    tabFragmentTwo.setArguments(args);
    return tabFragmentTwo;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    example_data = getArguments().getString(ARG_EXAMPLE);
    Log.i("Fragment created with ", example_data);


}

public static String[] split = new String[]{
        "none","blue","turquoise","ino","pallid","cinnamon","opaline","dom.pied","clearhead","cleartail"
};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    final TextView TV_Split = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSplits);
    final Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_split);
    Button button_clrSplit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_clr_split_selection);

    String[] sex = {
            "Select Gender...",
            "Cock", "Hen"
    };

    String[] mutation = {
            "Select mutation...",
            "Violet","Grey","Grey Green","Green","Dark Green","Blue","Dark Blue","Cinnamon Blue","Turquoise","Lutino","Albino","Blue Pallid","Green Pallid","Violet Pallid","Blue Pallidino","Green Pallidino","Violet Pallidino","Turquoise Blue","Turquoise Violet","Turquoise Blue Pallidino","Turquoise Violet Pallidino","Blue Opaline","Dark Blue Opaline","Cinnamon Blue Opaline",
            "Albino Opaline","Lutino Opaline","Blue Pallid Opaline","Green Pallid Opaline","Violet Pallid Opaline","Blue Pallidino Opaline","Green Pallidino Opaline","Violet Pallidino Opaline","Violet dom.pied","Grey dom.pied","Grey Green dom.pied","Green dom.pied","Dark Green dom.pied","Blue dom.pied","Dark Blue dom.pied","Cinnamon Blue dom.pied","Cinnamon Violet dom.pied","Turquoise dom.pied","Albino dom.pied","Lutino dom.pied","Blue Pallid dom.pied","Green Pallid dom.pied","Violet Pallid dom.pied","Blue Pallidino dom.pied","Green Pallidino dom.pied",
            "Violet Pallidino dom.pied","Turquoise Blue dom.pied","Turquoise Violet dom.pied","Turquoise Blue Pallidino dom.pied","Turquoise Violet Pallidino dom.pied","Violet dom.pied Opaline","Grey dom.pied Opaline","Grey Green dom.pied Opaline","Green dom.pied Opaline","Dark Green dom.pied Opaline","Blue dom.pied Opaline","Dark Blue dom.pied Opaline","Cinnamon Blue dom.pied Opaline","Cinnamon Violet dom.pied Opaline","Turquoise dom.pied Opaline","Albino dom.pied Opaline","Lutino dom.pied Opaline","Blue Pallid dom.pied Opaline","Green Pallid dom.pied Opaline","Violet Pallid dom.pied Opaline","Blue Pallidino dom.pied Opaline","Green Pallidino dom.pied Opaline","Violet Pallidino dom.pied Opaline","Turquoise Blue dom.pied Opaline","Turquoise Violet dom.pied Opaline",
            "Turquoise Blue Pallidino dom.pied Opaline","Turquoise Violet Pallidino dom.pied Opaline","Violet clearhead","Grey clearhead","Grey Green clearhead","Green clearhead","Dark Green clearhead","Blue clearhead","Dark Blue clearhead","Cinnamon Blue clearhead","Cinnamon Violet clearhead","Turquoise clearhead","Albino clearhead","Lutino clearhead","Blue Pallid clearhead","Green Pallid clearhead","Violet Pallid clearhead","Blue Pallidino clearhead","Green Pallidino clearhead","Violet Pallidino clearhead","Turquoise Blue clearhead","Turquoise Violet clearhead","Turquoise Blue Pallidino clearhead","Turquoise Violet Pallidino clearhead","Violet cleartail",
            "Grey cleartail","Grey Green cleartail","Green cleartail","Dark Green cleartail","Blue cleartail","Dark Blue cleartail","Cinnamon Blue cleartail","Cinnamon Violet cleartail","Turquoise cleartail","Albino cleartail","Lutino cleartail","Blue Pallid cleartail","Green Pallid cleartail","Violet Pallid cleartail","Blue Pallidino cleartail","Green Pallidino cleartail","Violet Pallidino cleartail","Turquoise Blue cleartail","Turquoise Violet cleartail","Turquoise Blue Pallidino cleartail","Turquoise Violet Pallidino cleartail",

    };

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sex);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spin_mutation = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spin_mutation);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_mutation = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mutation);
    adapter_mutation.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin_mutation.setAdapter(adapter_mutation);


    final List<String> splitList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));

    final Spinner spinner_split = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spin_split);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_splits = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, splitList);
    adapter_splits.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner_split.setAdapter(adapter_splits);


    button_clrSplit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "button clearSplit pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            splitList.clear();
            Collections.addAll(splitList, split);
            var_selected_Split =null;
            TV_Split.setText("");
            adapter_splits.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "button add pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            if(spinner_split != null && spinner_split.getSelectedItem()!=null){

                if(var_selected_Split!= null){
                    var_selected_Split = var_selected_Split+ (String) spinner_split.getSelectedItem()+"/";
                    int spinnerValue1 = spinner_split.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    splitList.remove(spinnerValue1);
                    adapter_splits.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    spinner_split.setSelection(0);


                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "position is is "+spinnerValue1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                }else{
                    var_selected_Split = (String) spinner_split.getSelectedItem()+"/";
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected is "+var_selected_Split, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        if (var_selected_Split.toString() == "none/"){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected is "+var_selected_Split, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                            int spinnerValue1 = spinner_split.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            splitList.remove(spinnerValue1);
                            button.setEnabled(false);

                        }else{
                            int spinnerValue1 = spinner_split.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            splitList.remove(spinnerValue1);
                            splitList.remove(0);
                            spinner_split.setSelection(0);
                            adapter_splits.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                }

                TV_Split.setText(var_selected_Split);

            }

        }
    });

    return v;
}
}
```

I will appreciate your help on this..

Comment: post initialization code of button.

Comment: First of all, are you sure your `if` condition (where you try to disable your button) can be true ?

Comment: @Daneel Thanks for throwing that question. I am not getting a true in my condition so I removed the +"/" and it is now working. thank you so much.. Because of this the button can now be disabled.. should I answer my own question? I can't give you a vote since you only post a  comment or vote for an answer from you :)